# is it possible to include Scripts and Styles in same Bundle ?(asp.net mvc5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification, scriptbundle, stylebundle

Attempting to use css and js files with same virtualpath bundle name 
   1 - is it possible ? (tried:but failed. cant define same virtual path name both for script and style)
   2 - it it possible to builtup a ScriptAndStyleBundle together included with a mixed bundle ?

Just because I wantto use **same name** both for css and js.

```
//in BundleConfig.cs
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/doMenu")
            .Include("~/Plugins/doMenu/files/js/doMenu.js")
            );

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/doMenu")
            .Include("~/Plugins/doMenu/files/css/doMenu.css")
            );
```

---

```
//in _PartialLayoutMenu.cs
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/doMenu")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/doMenu")
```

---

result is:

```
<!--MENU LAYOUT-->
<script src="/Plugins/doMenu/files/css/doMenu.css"></script>

<link href="/Plugins/doMenu/files/css/doMenu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!--/MENU LAYOUT-->
```

any clue ? or I want such a useless mind ?(thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/), which does support this feature.

Configuration:

```
bundles.Add<ScriptBundle>(BundleNames.Grid,
                          new[] {"~/Scripts/Grid.js"},
                          bundle => bundle.AddReference("~/" + BundleNames.Base));

bundles.Add<StylesheetBundle>(BundleNames.Grid,
                              new[] {"~/Content/Grid.less"});
```

`BundleNames` is a helper class I have with constant strings.

Reference bundles in views:

```
@{
    Bundles.Reference(BundleNames.Grid);
}
```

As you'd expect, this will include all CSS and JS, in the correct order.

I'd also mention that I've started using Cassette before ASP.Net had bundle management and I'm very happy with it. I didn't find any interesting feature ASP.Net had that I'm missing.

Comment: I render bundle in PartialLayout, and calling it @Html.Partial("_Menu")thus it doesnt put css link into header section.I read about this issue solved by casette can do it? but this is another question.

Comment: @N.Ramos - Yes, Cassette can handle that easily - it is designed for that. It makes sure each bundle is only included once, and they are all in the right order. Actually, I'd be very disappointed without this feature, I use it a lot (for example, a partial view that requires MathJax or DropzoneJS)

Comment: it seems I acciently underestimated the power of "casette". thanks for answers. that helps me alot.

Answer (score 3):

Bundle names should be unique within the both styles and scripts. And since they are entirely different types you cannot mix them into a single bundle because then you wouldn't know how to reference it in the DOM: whether you should use a `<script>` or a `<style>` tag. Unfortunately what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: to look an answer in current standards: yes its not possible but:
"casette" is great . solved this issue flawlessly.